# Where does document.referrer come from?

Tags: javascript, http, http-referer

I have the following script at http://localhost/test.html:

```
<script>
alert(document.referrer);
</script>
```

If I access it directly the result is an empty alert, which isn't surprising.

If I link from a different document at http://example.com/different.html, the alert will be that URL, again, not surprising.

What is suprising to me is that, if I intercept the HTTP request and change the Referer Header:

```
GET /test.html HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
Referer: test
```

Then the alert will still alert the original URL, not `test`.

So where does document.referrer come from if not from the referer HTTP Header? Is it not influenced by the HTTP request at all? Is there a standard for this, or do different browsers handle it differently? And is there a way to influence it, without creating a new file linking to the code myself?

Comment: Googling it gave me multiple discussions on that topic + definitions

Comment: The navigator set document.referrer, it's the page that linked the current page, so even if you try to set programmatically, when you navigate it will change.

Comment: @Jonasw I also googled and found nothing answering my question. If you have any links, I'd be glad to take a look.

Comment: @Jonasw A generic answer like "URI of the page that linked to the current page" doesn't really answer my question. I want to know what exactly is setting `document.referrer` and based on what information it is doing this. What I am finding are a lot of questions about getting the HTTP referer header, which are - falsely - answered with `document.referrer`. Ricardos navigator suggestion seems to be closer to what I want, but isn't very specific, and isn't what I found via google.

Comment: As javascript runs in a browser, this depends on the browser you are using. Even if you specify the browser we still cant answer because i dont want to mess with so much code. Its a fact that your browser does not take your refferer value, and i dont know any case where you really need to set it

Comment: @Jonasw I tried in Firefox and Chrome, the behavior is the same. I thought there might be some standard that defines where the value comes from that I might have missed, or that it may at least be handled the same in all modern browsers. "It's too much work to answer" doesn't seem like a good reason to dismiss a question. One situation where I would want to set it is when doing security testing. Setting the Referer HTTP header or something similar to that would be a lot easier for testing than having to create new files all the time that link to the script which uses document.referrer.

Comment: @tim : theres a standard but that doesnt mean that everybody is following it.

Comment: @Jonasw sure, that's always a problem with standards. Do you have a link?

Comment: https://dom.spec.whatwg.org

Comment: @Jonasw Well sure, the DOM is standardized, but that doesn't really help me. The link also doesn't mention `referrer` or `referer`.

Answer (score 1):

Referrer header your have intercepted is the request done by the client to the server. The client already know which is the referring page, you cannot fool it.

Answer (score 0):

Per MDN documentation:

document.referrer:

> Returns the URI of the page that linked to this page.

Further notes on why it displays empty to you:

> The value is an empty string if the user navigated to the page
> directly (not through a link, but, for example, via a bookmark). Since
> this property returns only a string, it does not give you DOM access
> to the referring page.

More info can be found at: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/referrer)

Now looking at the developer tools from both Chrome, Firefox and IE I can see the header is being set to: Referer:https://www.google.com/ whenever I hit a search result from google and this value is being set automatically by the browser. How it's set depends on browser implementor but this is the corresponding document describing the header value [RFC 7231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-5.5.2)

> The "Referer" [sic] header field allows the user agent to specify a
> URI reference for the resource from which the target URI was obtained
> (i.e., the "referrer", though the field name is misspelled).

Comment: This doesn't really answer my question. My issue is that `document.referrer` is **not** set via the HTTP `Referer` header.

Comment: I can intercept HTTP requests and set any header to anything I want via addons such as tamper data or via interception proxies.

Comment: Then perhaps this document can help : https://w3c.github.io/webappsec-referrer-policy which describes the process the browser goes through to set the Referer http header.

Comment: That is actually about how a server can control the Referer header for outgoing links (which is rather interesting, so thanks for the link :). But it's also just a working draft, firefox for example doesn't seem to have implemented it yet. Chrome on the other hand has, and it does affect the Referer HTTP header as well as document.referrer (as it should)

Answer (score 0):

The value is set by the browser, I mean the browser is setting the value "test" when you are doing the http request.

Comment: But the thing is, the browser is **not** setting the value "test" to `document.referrer`. So the HTTP Referer Header is not used for this.